# Use Proguard only to disable logging and for shrinking resources

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

**build.gradle:**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.SginConfig
        }
}
```

I don't want Proguard to optimize, or obfuscates my code as it is causing me a lot of trouble. I only want to remove log calls and enable shrinking of unused resources.

**proguard-rules.pro:**

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

Adding the code above to `proguard-rules.pro` work only if I set getDefaultProguardFile from `('proguard-android.txt')` to `('proguard-android-optimize.txt')`

But by setting it to `proguard-android-optimize.txt` would enable optimization flags which I don't want in my case.

So how can I just disable logging and shrink resources without Proguard's doing any minifying or optimizations to my code?

Comment: You can't. The `minifying` is apart of the `optimizations`. `assumenosideeffects` is apart of that.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this by only enabling the specific Proguard optimizations that `assumenosideeffects` depends on. The two that it depends on are:

- **code/removal/simple**: Removes dead code based on a simple control flow analysis.
- **code/removal/advanced**: Removes dead code based on control flow analysis and data flow analysis.

You can read more about the different optimization options [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/optimizations.html). So something like this should work:

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-optimizations code/removal/simple,code/removal/advanced
-dontobfuscate
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.SginConfig
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can still try using options like `-dontobfuscate` & `dontshrink` in your proguard configuration file. These options will not shrink and obfuscate the code.